# Where and how to add/edit css in roots starter theme

Tags: php, css, wordpress, gruntjs, npm

So i downloaded roots starter theme, installed node and run npm install etc. I have a working theme now. As i am modifying the PHP code my styles has to be synced with it. I do not understand where should i write my additional css and where should i edit existing css.

For example i created a footer menu and it markedup like

```
  <ul id="menu-footer" class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="menu-privacy-policy"><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
    <li class="menu-terms-conditions"><a href="#">Terms &amp; Conditions</a></li>
    <li class="menu-our-pledge"><a href="#">Our Pledge</a></li>
  </ul>
```

I have to add additional style to `#menu-footer` and edit bootstrap style of `.nav navbar-nav` It is my first time experience of looking at less, grunt , npm etc and i am in a feeling that i should not edit the `assets/main.css` files directly.

I want any reference link or advice what is the standard way of working with these type of files

Thanks

Comment: CSS is ussually locate in html head.

Comment: Did you read my question ?

Comment: http://www.htmldog.com/guides/css/beginner/

Comment: @jbutler483 My question is not about learning css. I asked what is the standard way of working with these type of files (.less files) and how roots theme recommend us to change styles.

Comment: Which is why this would be deemed off topic here. @RaheelKhan

Comment: I would start with learning about Grunt (http://gruntjs.com/getting-started) and how to run it as this is what you'll use to compile your LESS into CSS. Then hit up the Roots blog (http://roots.io/blog) for some how-tos and then check out the Roots forum (http://discourse.roots.io/) for additional help that will be more specific to the Roots workflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://roots.io/roots-101/#theme-assets

Where you put your custom styles is going to vary on what your styling. For example, Roots comes with a .less file specifically for the homepage and another specifically for styling the header or footer. This allows you to keep your styles separated and easier to maintain.

Comment: so rather then adding my custom styles to css files i have to write it on .less files and compile it ?

Comment: Correct. Don't make changes to your CSS files as they will be overwritten when you compile your .less files.